# RestKit POST object with NULL parameters

Tags: objective-c, post, http-post, restkit, restkit-0.20

If you have deep knowledge of RESTKit, your input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I try to POST a core data entity to the server, it connects fine but the server gives me back a response telling me all the parameters are NULL. I know the service works because I did the same service call with AFNetworking. Unfortunately I don't have free access to the server.

Here’s what I did. I created a core data entity

```
PDRepresentative *representative = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PDRepresentative" inManagedObjectContext:context];
representative.address1 = @"address1";
representative.address2 = @"address2";
representative.city = @"city";
representative.city = @"city";
representative.company = @"company";
representative.country = @"country";
representative.email = @"email";
representative.fax = @"fax";
representative.firstName = @"TestFirst";
representative.lastName = @"lastName";
representative.middleName = @"middleName";
representative.phone = @"phone";
representative.phonePersonal = @"phonePersonal";
representative.repId = @"TEST_REP_ID";
representative.specialty = @"spec";
representative.state = @"state";
representative.zip = @"zip";
representative.event = event;

//Create the mapping
RKObjectMapping *postObjectMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[postObjectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"repId":@"RepId",
                                                        @"firstName":@"First",
                                                        @"middleName": @"Middle",
                                                        @"lastName": @"Last",
                                                        @"address1": @"Address1",
                                                        @"address2": @"Address2",
                                                        @"city": @"City",
                                                        @"zip": @"Zip",
                                                        @"country": @"Country",
                                                        @"company": @"Company",
                                                        @"phone": @"Phone",
                                                        @"phonePersonal": @"PhonePersonal",
                                                        @"fax": @"Fax",
                                                        @"email": @"Email",
                                                        @"event.eventId": @"EventId",
                                                        @"specialty": @"Specialty"}];
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:postObjectMapping
                                                                               objectClass:[PDRepresentative class]
                                                                               rootKeyPath:@"PostAddOrUpdateRep"
                                                                                    method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];


//… assign the response descriptor

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [objectManager requestWithObject:representative method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"PostAddOrUpdateRep" parameters:nil];
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                               success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
                                                                                   NSLog(@"http body %@", test);
                                                                                   NSLog(@"error %@", error);

                                                                                   PDResponse *response = mappingResult.firstObject;
                                                                                   response = [response isKindOfClass:[PDResponse class]] ? response : nil;
                                                                                   TRACE_LOG(@"%@", response);
                                                                               }
                                                                               failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
                                                                                   NSLog(@"operation %@, error %@", operation, error);
                                                                               }];
[objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

I used this method of posting objects rather than using postObject:path:parameters:success:failure because it was assigning the target object to be the same as the request object but this would throw up an error because the response object is completely different from what is being sent. It would call RKMapperOperation addError. It was saying something along the line of, it was expecting the request object class but got the response object class.

Something else to note

If I run this after I get the request

```
// check the http body
NSDictionary *test = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:request.HTTPBody
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];
NSLog(@"http body %@", test);
NSLog(@"error %@", error);
```

It gives me the following output

```
2014-01-07 20:15:43.626 xctest[65449:303] http body (null)
2014-01-07 20:15:43.627 xctest[65449:303] error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x2a49940 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

Another thing to note, I did some testing and observed that the http body was created from the following dictionary

```
(lldb) po [objectParameters requestParameters]
{
    "PostAddOrUpdateRep" =     {
        Address1 = address1;
        Address2 = address2;
        City = city;
        Company = company;
        Country = country;
        Email = email;
        EventId = EventId;
        Fax = fax;
        First = TestFirst;
        Last = lastName;
        Middle = middleName;
        Phone = phone;
        PhonePersonal = phonePersonal;
        RepId = "TEST_REP_ID";
        Specialty = spec;
        Zip = zip;
    };
}
```

Which doesn’t seem right. I went ahead and changed the http body, to be the same as the HTTP body of the request created by AFNetworking, which was properly deserialized from NSJSONSerialization, and the server still gives me back an exception telling me that all parameters were NULL.

Here’s the code for working AFNetworking code

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient;
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"RepId": @"123",
                             @"First": @"Jack",
                             @"Middle": @"Q",
                             @"Last": @"Public",
                             @"Address1": @"sample string 5",
                             @"Address2": @"sample string 6",
                             @"City": @"sample string 7",
                             @"State": @"sample string 8",
                             @"Zip": @"sample string 9",
                             @"Country": @"sample string 10",
                             @"Company": @"sample string 11",
                             @"Phone": @"sample string 12",
                             @"PhonePersonal": @"sample string 13",
                             @"Fax": @"sample string 14",
                             @"Email": @"sample string 15",
                             @"Specialty": @"sample string 16",
                             @"EventId": @"EventId"
                             };

client.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"PostAddOrUpdateRep" parameters:parameters];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [client HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                                        TRACE_LOG(@"%s \nResponseObject %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, responseObject);
                                                                    }

                                                                    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                        TRACE_LOG(@"Operation %@", operation);
                                                                        TRACE_LOG(@"Error %@", error);
                                                                    }];
[client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

// check the http body
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *test = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:request.HTTPBody
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];
NSLog(@"http body %@", test);
NSLog(@"error %@", error);

The console output

2014-01-07 20:24:16.370 xctest[65939:303] http body {
    Address1 = "sample string 5";
    Address2 = "sample string 6";
    City = "sample string 7";
    Company = "sample string 11";
    Country = "sample string 10";
    Email = "sample string 15";
    EventId = EventId;
    Fax = "sample string 14";
    First = Jack;
    Last = Public;
    Middle = Q;
    Phone = "sample string 12";
    PhonePersonal = "sample string 13";
    RepId = 123;
    Specialty = "sample string 16";
    State = "sample string 8";
    Zip = "sample string 9";
}
2014-01-07 20:24:16.371 xctest[65939:303] error (null)
2014-01-07 20:24:16.373 xctest[65939:303] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:180 POST 'http://192.168.xxx.xxx/PostAddOrUpdateRep/1'
2014-01-07 20:24:18.755 xctest[65939:303] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:216 POST 'http://192.168.xxx.xxx/PostAddOrUpdateRep/1' (200 OK) [2.3812 s]
2014-01-07 20:24:24.473 xctest[65939:303] __20-[PMGRepTests test2]_block_invoke
ResponseObject {
    Ex = "<null>";
    Message = "";
    Success = 1;
    TransactionId = 1;
    Value =     {
        Address1 = "sample string 5";
        Address2 = "sample string 6";
        City = "sample string 7";
        Company = "sample string 11";
        Country = "sample string 10";
        Email = "sample string 15";
        EventId = EventId;
        Fax = "sample string 14";
        First = Jack;
        Last = Public;
        Middle = Q;
        Phone = "sample string 12";
        PhonePersonal = "sample string 13";
        RepId = 123;
        Specialty = "sample string 16";
        State = "sample string 8";
        Zip = "sample string 9";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RestKit you don't appear to be setting the request serialisation type to JSON ( the default is form URL encoded).

You also don't want `rootKeyPath:@"PostAddOrUpdateRep"` on your request descriptor, it should be set to `nil`.